# okhttp3 unable to find acceptable protocol

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish, okhttp

I'm using the following setup InteliiJ + java 8 + Webservice + OkHTTP(3.12.12) + Glassfish (4.1.1)to call a REST Api but facing some issue when connecting to it

> java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols.
> isFallback=false,
> modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
> TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_CCM_8_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA],
> tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2, TLS_1_1, TLS_1_0],
> supportsTlsExtensions=true), ConnectionSpec()], supported
> protocols=[TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]

My suspect for this would be the TLS version issue i.e. I'm calling via OkHTTP with a lower TLS.But JDK 8 is using TLS 1.2 by default. I've also set the TLS to be set at TLS 1.2 on code still no result.Now I'm wondering what other setting would cause this issue.I'm sorry this is my first time building a webservice using java.If there's other setting that I need to do please let me know.

My code below

```
 ConnectionSpec requireTLS12 = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
               .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
               .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(requireTLS12))
                .build();     
                
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/all")
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "key_key_key")
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            ResponseLah = response.body().string();
            // ... do something with response
            return ResponseLah;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Does this help? You might not have any intersection between client and server. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com

Comment: I'm sorry  @JesseWilson I don't understand does this mean that the reason why its showing the error is because "there's no medium to talk to it" i.e. like a trusted certificate ?

Comment: Your server and client need to support enough protocols that there's an intersection.